# Can I cast CFMutableDictionaryRef to CFDictionaryRef?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, core-foundation, reinterpret-cast

Function is expecting a CFDictionaryRef return:

```
CFDictionaryRef xyz()
{
CFMutableDictionaryRef test = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 1, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFDictionarySetValue(test, CFSTR("Test"), CFSTR("Test"));

return reinterpret_cast<CFDictionaryRef>(test);
}
```

Can a reinterpret_cast be used to convert? throws me a null ptr.

Comment: Can't you just return `test`?  A mutable dictionary is a subclass of a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely do as follows:

```
CFDictionaryRef xyz()
{
    CFMutableDictionaryRef test = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 1, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    CFDictionarySetValue(test, CFSTR("Test"), CFSTR("Test"));

    return (CFDictionaryRef)test;
}
```